# Sqlite3: Selecting from multiple tables without duplicates

Tags: join, sqlite, intersect

I've got three tables:

```
paper:             items:               attachments:
============       ==============       ==============
jkey | title       itemID | jkey*       itemID* | path
```

*foreign key from another table

I'm trying to retrieve the title of all papers and their associated attachment paths, for all papers that have attachments.

Current attempt is:

```
SELECT paper.title,attachments.path IN paper,attachments
WHERE paper.jkey IN (
    SELECT items.jkey FROM items,attachments
    WHERE items.itemID = attachments.itemID
);
```

Unfortunately this just seems to print gibberish (the same path for different titles and vice versa).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to join, you should use joins:

```
SELECT paper.title,
       attachments.path
FROM paper
JOIN items USING (jkey)
JOIN attachments USING (itemID);
```

To omit duplicate rows, use `SELECT DISTINCT ...` instead.

Comment: Just for my own understanding, the first `join` statement joins paper and items under jkey, and second `join` statement joins items and attachment under itemID?

Comment: Yes. (See the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#fromclause).)